# Can`t locate file for: -lSSH in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssh

I have a project that in xcode 4.6.3 perform the build with success, I compile the project in xcode 6.3.1, but the build not finish with success.
The error that the xcode show is:

```
Libtool
/Users/close-up/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-evjyzdzrjygbcohkrgjjjpfptjca/Build/Intermediates/MBAConnectivity.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBAConnectivity.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMBAConnectivity.a
normal armv7
    cd "/Users/close-up/Desktop/mobile-analyzer 2/ios/MBAConnectivity"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool
-static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
-L/Users/close-up/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-evjyzdzrjygbcohkrgjjjpfptjca/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-L/Users/close-up/Desktop/mobile-analyzer\ 2/ios/MBAConnectivity/../../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-chbhigkodhumkkgonnzdazlpxwaz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-L/Users/close-up/Desktop/mobile-analyzer\ 2/ios/MBAConnectivity/../../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-bduwdwhwrwewblbpyugnlvkdnewa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-filelist /Users/close-up/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-evjyzdzrjygbcohkrgjjjpfptjca/Build/Intermediates/MBAConnectivity.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBAConnectivity.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MBAConnectivity.LinkFileList
-lSSH -lUtil -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -o /Users/close-up/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MBAiOS-evjyzdzrjygbcohkrgjjjpfptjca/Build/Intermediates/MBAConnectivity.build/Debug-iphoneos/MBAConnectivity.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMBAConnectivity.a

error:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
can't locate file for: -lSSH error:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
file: -lSSH is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

believe that error occurred for cause the `libssh2` be outdated

thanks for help
André Vieira

Comment: Have you installed the updated command line tools for Xcode 6?

Comment: Yes, I have the updated command line tools for Xcode 6